# how to get a value when an element is clicked and then action a function

Tags: angularjs

I am very proficient in jquery and I just began learning angularjs yesterday. Now, there's something I want to do. I want to have like 2 tabs say in form of li elements. I want that when i click the a certain li element, it will set the current one clicked to say an active class which will have a different one from the other li element tab and then remove text in that li element(in jquery its $('li').text()) and then actions a getJson request to a webservice API. My guess is that the getJson request will be in a controller.

Please help with this. I don't know how to even start and what code to write. so if you can provide me with just little code so i can see the syntax as i am not familiar with angularjs syntax yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
html:
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div data-hbo-tabs id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1" ng-click="tab1()">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2" ng-click="tab2()">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Content for Tab 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Content for Tab 2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Content for Tab 3</p>
    </div>
</div>

    </div>
js :
var app=angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.tab1=function(){
        alert("tab 1 service call goes here");
    }
    $scope.tab2=function(){
        alert("tab 2 service call goes here");
    }
})
.directive('hboTabs', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
            var jqueryElm = $(elm[0]);
            $(jqueryElm).tabs()
        }
    };
})
```

Reference :

[Tab sample written in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/francisstalin/uPNDf/2/)

Answer (score 0):

First define a model.

JS

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $http) {
     $scope.tabs = [
        { title: 'Tab 1', contents:'' }, 
        { title: 'Tab 2', contents:'' }];


     $scope.setActive = function(tab) {
         $http({ url: '/getTabs', method:'GET'})
              .success(function(data) {
                   tab.contents = data;
              });
         $scope.selectedTab = tab;
     }
     $scope.setActive($scope.tabs[0]);
});
```

Next bind to your model in your view.

HTML

```
 <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
   <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-click="setActive(tab)" 
           ng-class="{'active': selectedTab == tab}"> {{ tab.title }}
           <div>
                 {{ tab.contents }}
           </div> 
       </li>
   </ul>
 </body>
```

This is a lot of code, but not much of an explanation. You should be able to see how everything fits together given that it is declarative and readable.